# How to publish my API specification using Apache?

Tags: swagger

I'm wondering whether it is possible to publish my RESP API specification in apache.

I tried to find an answer using Google, but I had no luck as there are a lot of "Apache Tomcat" or "Apache Licence" hits.

So I created my REST API specification using Swagger Editor and saved it as YAML, so I have `my-api.yml`.

What do I have to do now?

Answer (score 1):

At the end what I did was, to download [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) and I used dist folder.

I just modified URL in `index.html` directing to my API JSON file (I converted yml to jsom in Swagger Editor), which is sitting next to `index.html`.

```js
    window.onload = function() {
      // Begin Swagger UI call region
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "my-api.json", // <-- change THIS
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
```

The apache configuration was as simple as

```xml
    <VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/swagger

        ErrorLog /var/www/swagger/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/swagger/logs/requests.log combined

        <Directory "/var/www/swagger">
            Options Indexes MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```